# fullpage.js scrolling with swipe does not work in some slides sometimes

Tags: cordova, scroll, swipe, fullpage.js

I've been building my first app for a mobile phone with phonegap. I have an android phone and I've found it quite challenging to make swiping work smoothly. Finally, I found fullpage.js which makes swiping left and right work perfectly. The problem is that I want to use only  left and right swiped to change slides but I need to be apply to scroll slides normally up and down on mobile. I have three slides. When I open my app, the first slide opens. I can scroll it up and down perfectly. When I swipe left, it changes to slide 2 BUT i cannot scroll it up or down. If I swipe left again, I get the slide 3 which I can scroll up and down perfectly. If I now swipe back to the slide 2, I can scroll it up and down perfectly as well.

Here's the code:

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section" id="section1">
        <div class="slide" id="slide1">
            <div class="aui">
                <!-- some html content here ->
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="slide" id="slide2">
            <div class="aui" id="page2">
                <!-- some html content here ->
            </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="slide" id="slide3">
            <div class="aui" id="page3">
                <!-- some html content here ->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    fullpage.initialize('#fullpage', {
        autoScrolling: false,
        normalScrollElements: '.aui',
        touchSensitivity: 3,
        menu: '#menu',
        css3:true
    });
```

Comment: Probably because of your use of `normalScrollElements`. But we'll never know as you don't provide any reproduction or enough code for us to know.